# swift 5 UIswitch value change was not working when using loadview method

Tags: ios, uiswitch, uiappearance, loadview

**I am following [this example](https://peterwitham.com/swift-archives/how-to-theme-an-ios-app-using-uiappearance/).**

```swift
@IBAction Func DarkButton(_sender:UISwitch) {
    if (sender.isOn) { 
        Theme.darkTheme() self.loadView()
    } else { 
        Theme.lightTheme()  self.loadView()
    }
}
```

I have `lightTheme()` and `darkTheme()` methods in a `Theme` struct.
When I call `self.loadview()`, the theme changes the first time but afterward the switch value is not changing.

Comment: Please see [mre].

Comment: If `loadView` means the `UIViewController` method please consider [*You should never call this method directly*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview)

Comment: @vadian, how to achieve the background color change without using loadview() method,